# logout user when it close browser in zend

Tags: zend-framework

I want to logout a user when browser window is closed so as to set its status "offline" in the database. It is quite easy to set the status "offline" when user clicks the logout button. But the problem comes when the browser window is closed or the session timeout expires for that user.

and my next question is

Also, help me with the below code:

```
<?php echo $this->formText('mobile', @$this->params['mobile'], array('required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false)); ?>
```

I have this code and I want mobile number to be 10 a digit number only. What changes should I make to have this validation on this field?

```
<?php echo $this->formText('email', @$this->params['email'], array('maxlength' => '255', 'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false)); ?>
```

Similarly I want to do in email, please suggest me what I have to do to make perfect email validation in this form tag.

Comment: I doubt that there is a reliable way to track user inactivity and browser closing by the user.

Answer (score 0):

About Logout, you could do it with Javascript and call the logout url.

Something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit(){
    return "please confirm..";
}
```

Comment: it s giving alert msg on every click on my application. i want show this msg only when user directly close tab or browser